# Pure java 3D (without libraries)

Tags: java, 3d

I was searching a way to emulate 3d graphics. I found the cherno project, but i realized that it doesn't explain correctly the way to obtain the 3d view. Is there a good tutorial (or a good explanation) that shows correctly how to do it (or how games like prelude of the chambered work with 3d graphics)? (whithout any libraries, only pure java)

Comment: Prelude of the Chambered seems to use affine transformations on plain bitmaps.

Comment: What if libraries are written in a pure Java?

Comment: No, i don't want any library because i don't want to display 3D graphics, i want to learn how it's done in popular 3d java pure games(such as POC),and implement my own technique(sorry for my bad english)